# 'float' object is not iterable error caused by list comprehension hitting np.NaN

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a Pandas data frame `df` that looks as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'result' : ['s17h10e7', 's5e3h2s105h90e15', np.NaN 
                               's300h200e100s5e3h2s105h90e15', 's12h9e3'],
                   'status' : ['yes', 'no', 'no', 'yes', 'no']})

df

        result                           status
0       s17h10e7                         yes
1       s5e3h2s105h90e15                 no
2       NaN                              no
3       s300h200e100s5e3h2s105h90e15     yes
4       s12h9e3                          no
```

I have a function `sum_number_after_code`, which sums the numbers immediately following a user-defined `code`:

```
def sum_numbers_after_code(string_to_read, code):
    code_indices = [i for i, char in enumerate(string_to_read) if char == code]
    
    number_of_sales = []    
    list_of_sales = []
   
    for idx in code_indices:
        temp_number = ['0']
        for character in string_to_read[idx + 1: ]:
            if not character.isdigit():
                break
            else:
                temp_number.append(character)
            
        number_of_sales = ''.join(temp_number)
        list_of_sales.append(int(number_of_sales))

    return(sum(list_of_sales))
```

Example:

```
sum_numbers_after_code('s5e3h2s105h90e15', 's')
>> 110
```

I'd like to add a `total_sales` column to `df` by applying this `sum_number_after_code` function.  The resulting `df` would look as follows:

```
        result                           status       total_sales
0       s17h10e7                         yes          17
1       s5e3h2s105h90e15                 no           0
2       NaN                              no           0
3       s300h200e100s5e3h2s105h90e15     yes          410
4       s12h9e3                          no           0
```

Here is the code I'm using to do this:

```
df['total_sales'] = df['result'].apply(sum_numbers_after_code, code='s')
```

The error message I get is:

```
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_21060/4289690068.py in sum_numbers_after_code(string_to_read, code)
      1 def sum_numbers_after_code(string_to_read, code):
----> 2     code_indices = [i for i, char in enumerate(string_to_read) if char == code]
      3 

TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Apparently, the `NaN` at index 2 in the `result` column is causing this error.

I can work around this error by checking if `string_to_read` is `NaN` (and returning 0 if yes) just above the `code_indices` list comprehension:

```
if pd.isnull(string_to_read):
    return 0

code_indices = [i for i, char in enumerate(string_to_read) if char == code]
```

But, I feel like this is cheating.  Is there a more elegant way?

Thanks!

Comment: In the first code block where you create the dataframe, the sample data has four rows, yet the result dataframe somehow has five rows.  Where did the `NaN` row come from?

Comment: Edited the sample code to create the `df`.  Thank you.

Comment: why is that cheating.  Checking that variables are the correct type is a normal part of programming.  What do you want to happen to the `nan` cell?

Comment: If there were any NaN values, I want the function to return zero.  My approach works, but might not be the most elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Use extract all, groupby and np.where

```
df = (df.assign(total_sales =df.result.str.extractall('((?<=s)\d+)')#extract value extract values preceded by user code
                .droplevel(level=1).groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.astype(int).sum()))#Sum by level
      
    )

#Conditionally eliminate unwanted totals
df['total_sales']= np.where(df.status=='yes',df['total_sales'], 0)

print(df)

         result    status  total_sales
0                      s17h10e7    yes           17
1              s5e3h2s105h90e15     no            0
2  s300h200e100s5e3h2s105h90e15    yes          410
3                       s12h9e3     no            0
```